# JavaScript function with same name in jquery ui tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have created a page that use jquery ui tabs and each tab load a page via ajax request.I have cached result of ajax request.My problem is inner javascript in my pages that loaded in tabs.For example I have linkClick function in both pages, when I am opening these pages linkClick function override with second method.
How I can separate these method in my project.

Sincerely you Mahmood Bagheri

Comment: make a common linkClick function which loaded when your parent page loaded.

Comment: the body of linkClick maybe difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a namespace and a closure for your code/application.

Something like this:

```
(function (global) {

    var MYAPP = {};

    MYAPP.linkClick = function () ....

    global.MYAPP = MYAPP;

})(this);
```

Then whenever you need `linkClick`, you use `MYAPP.linkClick` and it does not get mixed with other names.

This way you avoid name collisions.

Answer (score 0):

It is very bad way to define functions in such way. Make functions less specific and add parameters, this functions preferably should be located in one file which should be loaded with other libs.

Comment: this is an exception.I set this function in a setting of grid and implement in my page.The logic of these functions maybe different.